# How to specify the instance from which a function is called

Tags: haskell

Say I have a type class such that for every instance a of this type class I have a function

```haskell
f :: [Bool] -> Maybe (a, [a])
```

How can I call f? More precisely, how can I specify that I mean the f from the instance of a and not from the instance of b if b is another type that is in this type class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you have to add type annotations. Consider the typeclass `Read`:

```
class Read a where
  read :: String -> a
```

If you try `read "1"` expecting to get the integer `1`, you'll get an error instead because there's no way to know what the type `a` is.  However, this works: `read "1" :: Int`.

If you are using your function `f` in a situation where the compiler can figure out what `a` is, then it'll work fine.  Otherwise, you have to help the compiler by adding appropriate type annotations.

Answer (score 3):

The typeclass instances are indexed by the specific types, for which they are declared. E.g., in the following case:

```
class YourClass a where
  f :: [Bool] -> Maybe (a, [a])

instance YourClass Int where
  f = error "Define me"

instance YourClass Char where
  f = error "Define me"
```

There are two unique instances of `YourClass`. One gets picked up, when `a` is `Int`, the other - when it is `Char`. The instances get resolved automatically using the types that the `f` function actually gets applied to.

So whenever you use `f` as if it has a specific signature `[Bool] -> Maybe (Int, [Int])`, the instance for `Int` gets picked up automatically. Since Haskell also has an incredibly powerful type inference, this specific signature doesn't really need to be specified in most cases, and the compiler resolves it from the context, again, automatically.

So basically, you can simply use that function on all types for which you have instances and safely expect the compiler to do the rest for you.

Comment: Ok, but arent there situations when this is ambiguous? For example in my specific case I want to use f in a case expression like this: case f xs of Nothing -> something... Just ( a, as) -> something else... How does haskell know which f I am using?

Comment: @user3726947 If the function, in which you have this expression, doesn't care which specific type "a" is, then it's a polymorphic function and will have a signature like `f2 :: (YourClass a) => a -> ...`

Answer (score 3):

To complement other answers, I'd point out that indeed some cases can be ambiguous.

For instance:

```
class C a where
  f :: String -> a
instance C Int where
  f s = length s
instance C Bool where
  f s = s == "hello!"

main :: IO ()
main = print (f "testing")
```

Now, `print` accepts any (`Show`able) type, and `f "testing"` can produce both a `Int` and a `Bool`. This is inherently ambiguous since the program above could print "False" as well as "7". There is no way that the compiler can figure that out.

As a solution we can use

```
main = print (f "testing" :: Int)
-- or
main = print (f "testing" :: Bool)
```

to disambiguate. Another less convenient option is

```
main = print ((f :: String -> Int) "testing")
```

or even, in GHC 8.0 with the right extension on,

```
main = print (f @ Int "testing")  -- explicit choice for type a
```

Note however that in some contexts there is no ambiguity, and GHC can do wonders. For instance:

```
main = print (f "testing" && True)         -- Bool is chosen here
main = print (f "testing" + length [1,2])  -- Int is chosen here
```

This is because `&&` requires `Bool`, and `length` returns `Int` while `+` forces the two arguments to have the same type (so `f "testing"` must be `Int` as well).

Also working

```
bar :: Bool -> Float
bar b = ...

main = print (bar (f "testing))  -- Bool is chosen
```